# Jquery filer.js Ajax request not sending updated variable value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

so Ive got this jquery plugin which is sending an ajax request to a php file with a variable attached. 
However the variable attached to data{type:filetype} is being changed on the page. When the user submits the request to be sent, the new value of the filetype is not being sent. 
Any idea why ?

The filetype variable is a global variable :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var filetype = "";
</script>
```

This is the plugin being initiated :

```
$('#filer_input1').filer({
            uploadFile: {
                url: "php/fileupload/upload.php",
                data: {order:19,
                        type:filetype},
                type: 'POST',
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                beforeSend: function(){
                    console.log(filetype);
                },
                success: function(data, el){
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(el);
                },
                error: function(el){
                },
                statusCode: null,
                onProgress: null,
                onComplete: null
            }
}
```

function which updates the variable :

```
function setFileType(x){
        var text = $("#"+x).html() + ' <span class="caret"></span>';
        $("#fileTypeSelect").html(text);
        filetype = x;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Well if you initiate it with one value and update the variable later, it does not update the plugin... You would need to update the plugin manually.

Comment: So your saying the plugin might be saving the value given when its initiated and just using that ?

Comment: The plugin is saving the initial value.